# strange behaviour with rect.dendrogram in dendextend package

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend

I try to show the influence of the cutoff height on the number of clusters using the `iris` dataset and visualize the resulting clusters with `rect.dendrogram`.

```
if (!require("dendextend")) {install.packages("dendextend")} else {library("dendextend")}

data("iris", package = "datasets")

Data <- list()

Data$Lab <- as.character(iris[,5])
Data$dat <- prcomp(iris[,-5])$x[,1:2]

Data$dist <- dist(Data$dat, method = "euclidean")
Data$hist <- hclust(Data$dist, method = "complete")

# plot dendrogram

hcd <- as.dendrogram(Data$hist)

cluster.height <- 6

par(pty = "m",
    mar = c(1,2,1.5,1),
    mgp = c(1,0,0),
    tck = 0.01,
    cex.axis = 0.75,
    font.main = 1)
plot(sort(hcd), 
     ylab = "Height",
     leaflab = "none")
rect.dendrogram(sort(hcd),
                h = cluster.height,
                border = "black",
                xpd = NA,
                lower_rect = -0.1,
                upper_rect = 0)
abline(h = cluster.height,
       lty = 3)
dev.off()
```

When using high height values, two rectangles appear.

[image: dendrogram_1]

The function searches for the clusters created by the cutoff.
The question is whether there is a way to obtain only the larger rectangle?
Is there a parameter/option that I have overlooked, or is it a bug in the `rect.dendrogram` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks indeed like some sort of bug to me, at least the function only seems to work with `"hclust"` objects but not with `"dendrogram"`s. You could use the relevant parts of the function.

```
> rect_dnd <- \(tree, which, h, ybadj=0, ytadj=0, ...) {
+   cl <- cutree(tree, h=h)
+   clt <- table(cl)[unique(cl[tree$order])]
+   m <- c(0, cumsum(clt))
+   k <- min(which(rev(tree$height) < h))
+   rect(xleft=m[which] + 0.66,
+        ybottom=mean(rev(tree$height)[(k - 1):k]) + ytadj,
+        xright=m[which + 1] + 0.33,
+        ytop=par()$usr[3] + ybadj, ...)
+ }
> 
> cluster.height <- 6
> 
> par(pty="m", mar=c(1, 2, 1.5, 1), mgp=c(1, 0, 0), tck=0.01, cex.axis=0.75, 
+     font.main=1)
> plot(hcd, ylab="Height", leaflab="none")
> rect_dnd(Data$hist, which=1, h=cluster.height, ytadj=-.1, border='red')
> abline(h=cluster.height, lty=3)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> Data <- list(Lab=as.character(iris[, 5]), dat=prcomp(iris[, -5])$x[, 1:2])
> Data$dist <- dist(Data$dat, method="euclidean")
> Data$hist <- hclust(Data$dist, method="complete")
> hcd <- as.dendrogram(Data$hist)
```

Comment: As suggested, I have slightly modified the source code from [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/dendextend/src/R/rect.dendrogram.R) and now only get one value for the higher y-value of the rectangle and accordingly only one rectangle per cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You could fall back to `rect.hclust` on which `rect.dendrogram` is based. `rect.hclust` allows to also specify `which` cluster should be highlighted. Example:

```
cluster.height = 6
pc <- prcomp(iris[-5])

Data <- list(labs = iris$Species,
             data = predict(pc)[,1:2],
             clusters = dat |>
               dist(method = 'euclidean') |>
               hclust(method = 'complete') |>
               sort()
             )

plot(Data$clusters)
rect.hclust(Data$clusters, h = cluster.height, which = 1)
```

see also `?identify.hclust` for interactive identification of dendrogram branches (=clusters)

[image: marking individual cluster]

Comment: Since I want the flexibility of the modifications from the ``dendentend`` package, I will stick with dendrogram since the ``which`` option is also available.